# pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "0-Definitions_Etudiant.tex"

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I tried to compile a tex file. The error is not clear and I cannot find what is causing it. I have searched in other forums but mostly it was because Miktek was not downloaded. Hence, I have made sure the Miktek is well installed but still get the same error and checked under Option->Execution Modes->Diagnosis.

This is what the Diagnosis says:

> Summary :-)
>
> Your TeX installation appears to be fine. If you experience problems
> after an application has been launched this usually isn't a
> WinEdt-related matter. In such case, you should test a problematic
> application from the Command Prompt, consult the documentation that
> comes with your (TeX) software, and try to locate the real source of
> your problem...
>
> When I look to the Searching for Executables, it says OK for every Tex
> executables (eg. TeX-Root: OK, TeX-Bin: OK,...)

I received the following error from the Console:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1
"0-Definitions_Etudiant.tex" Startup Folder: F:\Project\Wrtitings\
 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3)
(preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering
extended mode (0-Definitions_Etudiant.tex LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch
level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>)
*
```

Thank you,

Any guidance would be appreciated,

Elodie

Comment: The text in the log you show is not an error but simply the normal startup banner, but then you show the `*` prompt which means tex went past the end of the file without seeing `\end{document}` or outputting any pages.  It looks like your input file is empty.

Comment: what is in `F:\Project\Wrtitings\0-Definitions_Etudiant.tex`  (it looks from the log as if it is empty, or has `\endinput` at the start.)

Comment: Hi, that makes sense that it was not working. It is not an empty file but it is a thesis document divided in different sections and I have been compiling one of the sections but not the main tex file that calls those sections. Thank you for your time.

Comment: normally a section would generate a "missing document" error if it tries to typeset text, as this had no error, and from the file name I gues it is a file of definitions so not an error just that it neither starts nor ends a document.  Incidentally at the `*` prompt you can type tex eg `\documentclass{article}` tex is waiting for input